# How do I use condition for $arrayElemAt in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb

I am calculating the Inspection count using $arrayElemAt but am returning all the element count. I need to get the count which having $projectdata.inspection_data.published == 'Y'

```
"inspection_count" : {$size: {"$ifNull":[{$arrayElemAt:["$projectdata.inspection_data",0]},[] ] } }
```

How do I get the count based upon condition

My Code :

```
 mongo.folder.aggregate([
                    {
                        $lookup:
                        {
                            from: 'inspections',
                            localField: '_id',
                            foreignField: 'projectID',
                            as: 'projectdata'
                        }        
                    },
                    { $match : {
                        $and: [ 
                             querydata
                        ]
                   }
                },
                    {
                        "$project": {
                            "folder_name" : "$folder_name",
                            "location_name": "$location_name", 
                            "architect_name" :"$architect_name",
                            "cover_img": "$cover_img",
                            "created_date" : "$created_date",
                            "parent_id":"$parent_id",
                            "share" : "$share",
                            "share_id":'$share_id',
                            "user_id": "$user_id",
                            "customer_id" : "$customer_id",
                            "download_access" :  "$download_access",
                            "inspection_count": {
                                "$size": {
                                  "$filter": {
                                    "input": "$projectdata.inspection_data",
                                    "as": "el",
                                    "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$el.published", "Y" ] }
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                    }
                ]).exec(function (err, response) {
                    console.log("Inside Parent Id 1")

                    console.log(response)

                            if(response){
                            response.splice(0, 0, responseparent);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            response  = responseparent;
                            }
                    if (err){ 


                         res.json({ 'folder': [], 'filelist': [] }); } else {

                            res.json({ 'folder': response, 'filelist': [] }); }
                });
```

now its showing :

```
[ { _id: 00000000d080d32e387121c2,
    folder_name: 'Eq1',
    location_name: 'Chennai',
    architect_name: 'Architect Hafeez',
    cover_img: '1539170072349-rmTeigYTa9pmjpdP.png',
    created_date: 2018-10-24T06:05:33.533Z,
    parent_id: [ 00000000d080d32e387121c0 ],
    share: 'N',
    share_id: [ 00000000d080d32e387121bf, 000000002ef020361c3d1ff7 ],
    user_id: 00000000400376127c1a8a31,
    customer_id: [ 00000000d080d32e387121bf ],
    download_access: 'Y',
    inspection_count: 21 },
 ]
```

Expectation:

```
[ { _id: 00000000d080d32e387121c2,
    folder_name: 'Eq1',
    location_name: 'Chennai',
    architect_name: 'Architect Hafeez',
    cover_img: '1539170072349-rmTeigYTa9pmjpdP.png',
    created_date: 2018-10-24T06:05:33.533Z,
    parent_id: [ 00000000d080d32e387121c0 ],
    share: 'N',
    share_id: [ 00000000d080d32e387121bf, 000000002ef020361c3d1ff7 ],
    user_id: 00000000400376127c1a8a31,
    customer_id: [ 00000000d080d32e387121bf ],
    download_access: 'Y',
    inspection_count: 3 },
 ]
```

Total 21 But I have to show only which having published status 'Y

Comment: Can you paste your document structure here for more info and what count you are planning to get?

Comment: $arrayElemAt returns only the element at given position. In your query, it will return only first element as denoted by 0. Your question suggests you are looking to get count based on some condition.

Comment: Yes I need count based upon condition

Comment: Can you paste some sample data or at least simple structure?

Comment: @Vishnu Can you add a sample data and an expected result?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54514244/size-in-mongodb-with-condition check this link and answer

Comment: I have updated my Code Kindly check

Comment: I think you are missing a unwind before $project. Unwind project data and provide input as $inspection_data.

Comment: @Akash I am getting undefined